# Writing an object to a file

Tags: java, file, serialization, binary-data

I need to write an entire object to a file and retrieve whenever I want. Suppose I want to write a object of a class "Student" which has attributes such as grades, name, roll etc.. And when I want to access and manipulate the attributes later whenever I need. Can you show me a way to accomplish it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ObjectOutputStream.

```
 public class Student implements Serializable {

 }

 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Students.dat");
 ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

 Student someStudent = new Student();

 oos.writeObject(someStudent);

 oos.close();
```

Like so.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Serialization](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do what you're looking for is [Object Serialization.](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/)

Basically, you add an interface to your `Student` class, `Serializable`, which will allow you to pass objects of that class to an `ObjectOutputStream`. You can use this stream to write those students to files on disk. Later, they can be read in via an `ObjectInputStream` to be modified again.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Java Serialization API](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/).

Answer (score 1):

If you have simple JavaBeans, you could use java.beans.XMLEncoder/ XMLDecoder.

Yet another way is to use JAXB.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to simply implement Java's Serializable interface: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html

```
public class Student implements Serializable {
}
```

You can then read/write using the readObject/writeObject methods.

Answer (score 0):

These methods should help you, your student class has to implement serilizable,
Use it like:

Student s1 = new Student();
objectToFile("test.ser",s1);
Student s2 = fileToObject("test.ser");

```
public static void objectToFile(String fileName, Serializable object){
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    try {
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName)));
        oos.writeObject(object);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally{
        try {
            oos.flush();
            oos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

public static Object fileToObject(String fileName){
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    try {
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName)));
        return ois.readObject();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    } finally{
        try {
            ois.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```